# вопросов по выводу данных

Tags: php

есть в таблице

```
ENUM '0','1',...,'30'
```

Каждое число, имеет свое название. Есть ли более компактный вывод, нежели

```
if ($a->b==0) $b = 'название0';
```

и тд. как-то убого оно смотрится.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обычно для этого используются массивы

```
$data = [
  0 => 'name0',
  1 => 'name1',
  ........
  30 => 'name30'
];
$b = $data[$a->b];
```

Или в БД заводится таблица классификатор

```
Names
  id | name
  -----------
  0  | 'name0'
  1  | 'name1'
  ........
  30 | 'name30'
```

И все выборки делаются с джойном этой таблицы